# How to open my jupyter notebook on docker after starting a docker?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I wanna start my container and run the jupyternotebook on it. The image is from jupyter/scipy.
First, I start my contianer. Then I try to command 'jupyter notebook' to open it but seems like the port is not 8888, it turns to 8889. I dont know how to deal with this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j19V7.png)

Comment: What do `$ docker run -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/~yourpath jupyter/scipy-notebook` and `docker container ls` return? Does 8889 port work? Also edit your post to include the error in text, not image.

Comment: I've solved this problem. Because everytime I start this container, a jupyter notebook is already exits. That's the reason why when I create another one, the port is 8889, not 8888. To see the existing jupyter notebook, I use docker logs jonas1 to shouw the log and get the jupyter notebook url